# React onClick: cannot read property 'functionName' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, spfx

I have a button that I'm trying to click in my React component that's supposed to execute a function with a parameter called "item" that is defined within the function that returns this pseudo-HTML:

```
<div>{item.creationDate}</div>
        <PrimaryButton text={strings.LangPointer}
          onClick={() => this.emitComponentId(item)}/>
```

When I try to run this, it gives me "Cannot read property `emitComponentId` of undefined.".

I've tried multiple solutions, and none of them work and give me the same error:

`onClick={this.emitComponentId.bind(this)}`

Defining
`this.emitComponentId = this.emitComponentId.bind(this)` in the component constructor

`() => this.emitComponentId(item).bind(this)` --> will not even let me compile because 'void' is not an acceptable return type

Basically nothing I've tried works and always gives me the same result.

Comment: What is the context of the first code above?  Is that within `render() {...}`, which is within a `export default class App extends React.Component {...}` definition?  Just trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: It's within a function called `renderTaskItem` which is called by a `onRenderCell` attribute in `render()`.

Comment: Okay if you add just the calling code?  Just looked over a working React example I have, are you calling it like `return ( ... {this.renderOtherThing()} ....)`?  Also, is this the only error?  Sometimes an earlier error will cascade into other errors.

Comment: yeah that's pretty much what I'm doing. I don't think there are other errors because it works fine without the onclick function, it's a new feature i'm working on.

Comment: Just dug up an example of one of my onClick's in React, I have it set like this, maybe this would be better?  `onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}`  (with the event?)  Also, `handleClick(e) {...}` is within the class def, obv.

Comment: `onClick={() => this.emitComponentId(item)}/>`  Maybe you need....? `onClick={(SomeItemArgumentHERE) => this.emitComponentId(item)}/>`

Comment: in that case wouldn't the argument that I'm passing be `item` in `this.emitComponentId(item)`?

Comment: did you try  define and bind your metod in component constructor ?

Comment: @Grumbunks: Yeah, something like that.  I don't have that much of the code to know what item is.  I tried making a working sandbox demo, using your exact code, works 100%: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-gvjyd?file=/index.js I noticed you have a custom button class, `PrimaryButton`, maybe the problem is hidden deeper in there?

Comment: @Bahtiyar yes, I did. I also tried to switch out PrimaryButton with just a normal HTML button and it's still giving me the same result. This is getting on my nerves to be honest.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you show the code in your component ?

Comment: Where and how is `emitComponent` defined? In the component that renders the `<div>`? And is that a class component?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding `.bind(this)` to the calling of the `renderTaskItem()` function